# How to place UIImageView randomly on X & Y axis but with linear mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, random, uiimageview

I have reached up to image shown in the snapshot.

But still its Y is at bottom only and I am not able to set the X properly overlapped.

Images at Y can be up and down but cannot have the same Y as of pervious Image.[image: I am at here]
Image at X have to be overlapped to previous but can not have distance between any of Image.

I was able to set Y but still It should be in the middle of screen and not at bottom and not able to set X.

This is the code I am using

```
    CGFloat randomX = (arc4random()%100) *1.1;
    CGFloat randomY = (arc4random()%100) *.40;

    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:path];

    NSLog(@"prevnode : %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(prevNodeCenter));

    attributes.size = CGSizeMake(ITEM_SIZE, ITEM_SIZE);
    attributes.center = CGPointMake(_center.x + _radius + randomX * cosf(2 * path.item * M_PI / _cellCount) ,
                                    _center.y  + _radius + randomY);

    NSLog(@"randomX : %f randomY : %f",randomX,randomY);
    NSLog(@"attrib center x : %f",attributes.center.x);

    /*
    if(attributes.center.x <= prevNodeCenter.x )
    {
        attributes.center = CGPointMake(prevNodeCenter.x+_radius+cosf(2 * path.item * M_PI / _cellCount), attributes.center.y);
    }
    if(attributes.center.x >= prevNodeCenter.x+_radius)
    {
        NSLog(@"its far");
    }
    */

     /*
    if(attributes.center.y > self.collectionView.frame.size.height)
    {
        attributes.center = CGPointMake(attributes.center.x, self.collectionView.frame.size.height/2);
    }*/

    prevNodeCenter = attributes.center;
    return attributes;
```

Comment: The library you're using is under NDA from iOS 6, please ask your question in the Apple developer forums.